# What do I get when i return a node in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, output

I made an ArrayList and added 4 Buttons to it with the names button1, button2, button3 and button4.
Then i wrote an funtion, that returns a random Node of the List.
It returns some strange code to me, but I only want the name like "button1", not **Button@35cb2a47[styleClass=button]"**.
What exactly returns the funtion, and how can i get the name of the node out of that.

Thanks everybody and sorry for bad pragramming style. I`m new to the game.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();

        Button button1 = new Button();
        list.add(button1);
        Button button2 = new Button();
        list.add(button2);
        Button button3 = new Button();
        list.add(button3);
        Button button4 = new Button();
        list.add(button4);

        System.out.println("" + getRandomNode(list));

    }

    public Node getRandomNode(List<Node> list){
        int ls = list.size();
        Random random = new Random();
        int randInt = random.nextInt();
        return list.get(Math.abs(randInt%ls));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The output of this is something like this = Button@6844c615[styleClass=button]''

Comment: The buttons don't have names. `button1`, `button2` etc. are local variables you have in your `start` method, which contain references to those buttons, and then you put those references into a List. What it returns is a reference to the button object. Now, what do you want to do with a button object?

Comment: Thank you so much, now I was able to get what i wanted. Thanks to you, you solved my problem.